# angularjs routing with object pass

Tags: angularjs

When i click on view Button from department list Data not showing on view template. i am not using any service. 
please help me someone.........

my source code is given below ......

My Angular js Controller:

```
.when('/Edit/:Id', {

            templateUrl: baseSiteUrlPath + 'Templates/Hrm_dept/Edit.html',
            controller: 'DeptCtrl'
        })

    $scope.DeptView = function (Dept) {
        console.log(Dept);
        $scope.Dept1 = angular.copy(Dept);
        var id = 1;
        var earl = '/Edit/' + id;
        $location.path(earl);
    };
```

My List template :

```
ng-click="DeptView(Dept)"
```

My View template:

```
ng-model="Dept1.DEPT_NAME"
```

Comment: i need asp.net mvc angularjs experts

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for above question for clear understanding.

Comment: i have 3 tepmlate pages
1. Create.html
2. List.html
3. Edit.html
Create and List is working well. when i am trying to go from list to Edit Template by clicking edit button the object which i am passing ng-click="DeptView(Dept)"  not showing in edit or view template. DeptView(Dept) function is exists in same controller.

Comment: create small example of what you are doing in plnkr.co

Comment: i have solved it. i have used extra another controller . thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

For This Your Code Should Be Like This

> listController.js

```
Bring List From Db and give to listController.Html
```

> In listController.Html it should contain **links** like this

```
<a ng-href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
<a ng-href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
<a ng-href="#/edit/{{project.$id}}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

> Router

```
.when('/edit/:projectId', {
controller:'detailController',
templateUrl:'detailController.html'
})
```

> detailController.js

```
.controller('detailController',function($location, $route){

    var projectId = $route.projectId,

    //getDataByIdFromDb
    $http.get('sales/getsalesbyid?id=' + projectId).then(function(response) 
    {
         populate result in html
    });  
});
```

Fore More reference refer [Angularjs Wire up a Backend](https://angularjs.org/)